# Как закрыть блок при удалении последнего элемента?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Есть интернет-магазин на wordpress+woocommerce в котором есть функционал сравнения товаров при помощи [плагина](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/yith-woocommerce-compare/). Хочу добавить функционал, чтобы при добавлении товара в сравнение всплывал дополнительный блок, а при удалении последнего товара из сравнительной таблицы блок исчезал. С добавлением все ок, а вот при удалении любого товара блок исчезает, а мне нужно, чтобы после последнего только. Делаю проверку на наличие таблицы **if (oTable) {}**, но, почему-то такую переменную не находит - пишет **Uncaught ReferenceError: is not defined**

```js
        var oTable;
        $('body').on('yith_woocompare_render_table', function() {
          jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            if ($(window).width() > 767) {
              oTable = $('table.compare-list').dataTable({
                "sScrollX": "100%",
                //"sScrollXInner": "150%",
                "bScrollInfinite": true,
                "bScrollCollapse": true,
                "bPaginate": false,
                "bSort": false,
                "bInfo": false,
                "bFilter": false,
                "bAutoWidth": false
              });

              new FixedColumns(oTable);
              $('<table class="compare-list" />').insertAfter($('h1')).hide();
            }
            $("#fix-bot", window.parent.document).show();
          }).trigger('yith_woocompare_render_table');

          $(window).on('yith_woocompare_product_removed', function() {
            if (oTable) {
              console.log('deleted!');
            }
            if ($(window).width() > 767) {
              oTable.fnDestroy(true);
            }
            $("#fix-bot", window.parent.document).hide();
            $('body').trigger('yith_woocompare_render_table');
          });

        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Всё верно. Если переменная не объявлена, то обращение к ней приводит к ошибке.

```js
if (typeof varToCheck === 'undefined' || varToCheck === null){
    alert ('varToCheck undefined or null');
} else {
    alert ('varToCheck not null')  ;
}
```

Comment: постойте-ка, но ведь следующая же за ней строчка `oTable.fnDestroy(true);` и там переменная почему-то объявлена